# Databricks SQL string_agg

Tags: sql, databricks

Hopefully a quick one;

Migrating some on-premise SQL views to Databricks and struggling to find conversions for some functions. the main one is the string_agg function.

string_agg(field_name, ', ')

Anyone know how to convert that to Databricks SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The rough equivalent would be using `collect_set` and `array_join` but note you have lost the order:

```
%sql
SELECT col1, array_join(collect_set(col2), ',') j
FROM tmp
GROUP BY col1
```

I do not think `STRING_AGG` guarantees order (unless you specify the `WITHIN GROUP...ORDER BY` clause) but you should expect the order **not** to match.  Hopefully the order does not matter to your process but you should double-check it does not have any implications for your process.  As per the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#collect_list):

> [`collect_list`] is non-deterministic because the order of collected
> results depends on the order of the rows which may be
> non-deterministic after a shuffle.

They have recently added the ordinal argument to `STRING_AGG` to Azure SQL DB, Managed Instance and Synapse, but presumably you don't yet have that feature on-premises anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the answer @wBob. I am able to guarantee sort by modifying your code in the following way:

```
array_join(array_sort(collect_set(col2)),",") j
```

The ***array_sort()*** sorts the items returned by ***collect_set()*** and ***array_join()*** converts that output into a single string.

Comment: Hi Ryan, array_sort certainly gives _an_ order but loses the _original_ order which I think is what we were getting at in the original post.  If this works for you though, and you’re use case, that’s great.

Comment: Hey Bob,

Thanks for  the clarification. Yes, this does work for my use case. I incorrectly assumed you all were talking about a regular sort and not the original sort order.

Answer (score 0):

Databricks SQL support is for basic SQL queries only . So procedure-oriented queries are not supported with current Databricks SQL version . This would fall under a new feature request. You can handle basic SQL functions only [link](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/index.html)

Note: Databricks SQL provides a simple experience for SQL users who want to run quick ad-hoc queries on their data lake, create multiple visualization types to explore query results from different perspectives, and build and share dashboards. It is not supposed to replace ETL workloads running in Python/PySpark which we are currently handling .

Comment: I’m sorry I couldn’t be more helpful with my answer . based on your ask , you are looking option Databricks SQL. but  @wBob answer is in spark SQL . Both are different altogether . Either one of the thing different . Based on the Databricks SQL , Still am stand on my answer.   Kindly modify question or answer depends use case what you are trying . Otherwise future ref will be lead wrong .Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: thanks for your response, wBob solution worked partly. I was looking for Databricks SQL not sparkSQL so you were correct in that sense. I have managed to use some of what wBob mentioned and tweaked it to get what I need.

Comment: Best of luck !! @JWorrell

Comment: Hi @JWorral, can you post the code you ended up using?  I think it will be interesting.

Answer (score -1):

You can use concat functions as described here
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#concat_ws

```
SELECT concat_ws(' ', 'Spark', 'SQL');
```