# Combine multiple rows that share the same ID

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I'm trying to combine comment rows that have the same id in the sequence order separated by '/ ' The data I need is in different databases & tables. I've tried GROUP BY, UNION, and AGGERGATE with no success.

Here is example sql code:

```
SELECT
F.ID
F.FRUIT
C.SEQUNENCE
C.COMMENT

FROM FRUIT F
LEFT JOIN COMMENT C 
ON F.ID = C.ID
```

Current result:

| ID | FRUIT | SEQUENCE | COMMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | APPLE | 1 | COMMENT1 |
| 1 | APPLE | 2 | COMMENT2 |
| 1 | APPLE | 3 | COMMENT3 |
| 2 | BANANA | 1 | COMMENT1 |
| 2 | BANANA | 2 | COMMENT2 |
| 3 | KIWI | 1 | COMMENT1 |

Desired result:

| ID | FRUIT | COMMENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | APPLE | COMMENT1/ COMMENT2/ COMMENT3 |
| 2 | BANANA | COMMENT1/ COMMENT2 |
| 3 | KIWI | COMMENT1 |

Thanks for the help - J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rough equivalent would be using collect_set and array_join but note you have lost the order:

```
SELECT
F.ID
,F.FRUIT
,array_join(array_sort(collect_set(str(sequence) + '-' + comment)), '/') 
FROM FRUIT F
LEFT JOIN COMMENT C 
ON F.ID = C.ID
GROUP BY F.ID, F.FRUIT
```

### test

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9757e/3

### STRING_AGG()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: STRING_AGG is not a function in Databricks, but that is exactly the function I need.

Comment: Oh, I see, look at my edit, extracted from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70018818/databricks-sql-string-agg

Comment: Do you think I could throw an Order by in there?

Comment: Could you expand on that? I have had to add array_join(collect_set(comment), "/ ") to a select subquery, due to other columns in my real data. I have added 
(SELECT array_join(collect_set(c.COMMENT), "/ ")
    FROM COMMENT c 
    WHERE f.ID = c.ID)) 
Where should I put the ORDER BY?

Comment: test my edit. If sorting works, you need to clean the output a little